# Hazelcast Map Expire Listener on key, race condition

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have IMap<Long, SomeObject> on hazelcast member,
where some part of `Long` keys have expiration time (TTL).

For this purpose I am registering [EntryExpiredListener](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/listener/EntryExpiredListener.html) on key using [addEntryListener(MapListener, K, boolean)](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#addEntryListener-com.hazelcast.core.EntryListener-K-boolean-).

Everything works fine, but I have doubts.

As [documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Events/Event_Listener_for_Members/Listening_for_Map_Events.html) states:

> With the above approach, there is the possibility of missing events between the creation of the instance and registering the listener. To overcome this race condition, Hazelcast allows you to register listeners in configuration.

Will I encounter 'missing events' described above, if I register `EntryExpiredListener` on key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it’s on the member & you mark the listener as local ( so each member receive only local expration events) and define in the config, you wont since events will be local to each member.

If you register the listener after you create the instance, after partitions distributed & before you register the listener, its possible that some data could expire. This is why above statements says you need to define listener in the config to prevent this.

Comment: But what about registering listener on key? I guess you cannot register on key listeners beforehand (in config). This means I still might miss events?

Comment: What do you mean by registering listeners on key? Can you give an example?

Comment: In my question above I included link:
https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#addEntryListener-com.hazelcast.core.EntryListener-K-boolean-

Comment: In this case,, yes, since you can only register the listener this way through IMap.